# Clean Ubuntu Server install, can't connect to docker registry

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Clean install of Ubuntu 19.04, installed Docker and docker-compose.  I'm able to connect to the internet, apt-get and other tools all connect fine, but I get the following error when trying to pull a container.

`ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 100.24.246.89:443: connect: network is unreachable`

I've tried changing the nameserver entries, but it doesn't help.  There are no firewalls or proxies.  Direct connection to the internet.  System was working until I had to wipe and reinstall after netplan puked.

How can this be so broken on a clean install?  What do I need to fix?

Comment: Did you try `traceroute`/`mtr` to that node? Or better to `registry.docker.io`? And what says `ip route`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the commenter reminding me to `traceroute registry.docker.io` and check `ip route`, it directed me to an issue with my netplan settings.  Apparently I made a mistake in the gateway4 value.

FYI, a symptom was that pinging a site worked, but traceroute gave an error.